# Fatal error when instanciating Pusher - Can't find class

Tags: php, namespaces, pusher

I have a project to test and play around, with the following structure:

```
app/
    controllers/
        HomeController.php
    handlers/
    models/
vendor/
    composer/
    psr/
    pusher/
        pusher-php-server/
            src/
                Pusher.php
                PusherException.php
                PusherInstance.php
            tests/
            composer.json
    autoload.php
index.php
```

I tried to require the Pusher autoloader in my index file:

```
require 'vendor/autoload.php';
```

Which is the following:

```
// autoload.php @generated by Composer
   require_once __DIR__ . '/composer/autoload_real.php';
   return ComposerAutoloaderInite16b90ab01042d2a69b1d54243c9e23a::getLoader();
```

Now, in my `HomeController.php`, I have the following code:

```
namespace App\controllers;

use \App\handlers\Views as View;
use \App\models\Home_model as Home;
use \App\controllers\SessionController;
use \Pusher\Pusher as Pusher;

class HomeController {

    private $pusher;

    public function __construct() {
        $options = array(
            'cluster' => 'hmm',
            'encrypted' => true
        );

        $this->pusher = new Pusher(
            'secret',
            'secret',
            'secret',
            $options
        );
    }

    public function index() {

        $data['message'] = 'hello world';
        $this->pusher->trigger('my-channel', 'my-event', $data);

        return $this->view->render('views/home/index.php');
    }
}
```

But this returns me an error:

```
Fatal error: Class 'Pusher\Pusher' not found in
```

And I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong. Could someone explain me what I'm doing wrong?

In `composer.json` I get the following:

```
{
    "name": "pusher/pusher-php-server",
    "description" : "Library for interacting with the Pusher REST API",
    "keywords": ["php-pusher-server", "pusher", "rest", "realtime", "real-time", "real time", "messaging", "push", "trigger", "publish", "events"],
    "license": "MIT",
    "require": {
        "php": "^5.4 || ^7.0",
        "ext-curl": "*",
        "psr/log": "^1.0"
    },
    "require-dev": {
        "phpunit/phpunit": "^4.8 || ^5.7"
    },
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "Pusher\\": "src/"
        }
    },
    "autoload-dev": {
        "psr-4": { "": "tests/" }
    },
    "config": {
        "preferred-install": "dist"
    },
    "extra": {
        "branch-alias": {
            "dev-master": "3.0-dev"
        }
    },
    "minimum-stability": "dev",
    "prefer-stable": true
}
```

On Github, they mention that the library depends on cURL and JSON modules.

Not realy sure if this has something to do with my issue?
I'm still stuck, so any help is greatly appreciated.

Also, I'm using a .htaccess file, to rewrite my urls.

Comment: Can you show us your `autoload.php` and more infos about directories under `vendor/pusher` ?

Comment: I've updated my question.

Comment: It looks like the namespace `Pusher ` is not well defined, can you find its declaration inside `composer.json` or inside the folder `vendor/composer`?

Comment: I've updated again, with the content of the composer.json file

Comment: Try a `composer dump-autoload -o`, to regenerate autoload. Can't help more, looks fine for me

Comment: Where is `class HomeController ...`? I see the `namespace` and `use` declarations and then `private $pusher` but no `class` declaration

Comment: True, I did not include it in here. This was an editing mistake. The class declaration however is available in the code. I'll edit it.

Comment: I made some progress on this issue. I've modified my autoloader, and included all the directories that were holding classes that Pusher uses.This seems to work, so my guess is that there's something wrong with the autoloader or the json file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have managed your code to work with right `composer.json` next to `index.php`:

```
{
    "name": "awesome/project",
    "type": "project",
    "license": "MIT",
    "authors": [
        {
            "name": "Author",
            "email": "author@gmail.com"
        }
    ],
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "": ""
        }
    },
    "require": {
        "pusher/pusher-php-server": "dev-master"    
    }
}
```

Then just run `composer install`.
My `index.php` contents:

```
<?php

require 'vendor/autoload.php';

use app\controllers\HomeController;

$ctrl = new HomeController();
```

Comment: I've tried it, but it still gives me the same error. There's no new behaviour. You do mean the composer file in the root of the project?

Comment: Yes.  And there should be required autoloader in index.php.

Comment: Check it out https://github.com/EgorBurykin/pusher. After cloning do ```composer install```. And then run ```php index.php```

Comment: That does indeed work, but not in my project. I did manage to make it work by including all the required directories in my autoloader.

Comment: Well, I just used information provided to solve problem. Indeed if you have different problem solution will be different.

Comment: @JeroenBellemans do you have `composer.json` before @EgorBurykin give it to you? If not, can you tell me your full `index.php`?